# Higher Algebra, Propositions 2.3.4.5 and 2.3.4.9

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories, higher-algebra

I am reading the proof of Propositions 2.3.4.5 of Higher Algebra by Jacob Lurie. There is a part that I don't understand, and I need someone's help.

In the book, Lurie introduces the notion of *families of $\infty$-operads*. As the name suggests, it is a "coherent collection" of $\infty$-operads parametrized by an $\infty$-category. Sometimes we can deduce a "global" property about a generalized $\infty$-operad from its "local" property. For instance, (a part of) Proposition 2.3.4.9 asserts the following:

> Let $S$ be a Kan complex and $\mathcal{O}^\otimes \to S\times N(\mathrm{Fin}_\ast)$ be an $S$-family of $\infty$-operads. Suppose that for each vertex $s$ of $S$, the forgetful functor $\mathrm{Alg}_{\mathcal{O}_s}(\mathcal{C})\to\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal{O}_s,\mathcal{C})$ admits a left adjoint. Then the forgetful functor $\mathrm{Alg}_{\mathcal{O}}(\mathcal{C})\to\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal{O},\mathcal{C})$ also has a left adjoint.

Like many other "local to global" principle in simplicial setting, the proof proceeds by a simplex-by-simplex argument. And what makes the simplex-by-simplex argument possible is the following fact (which appears at the end of the first paragraph of the proof of 2.3.4.9):

> For each simplex $\Delta^n\to S$, the inclusion $$\mathcal{O}^\otimes \times _S \{0\}\hookrightarrow\mathcal{O}^\otimes \times _S\Delta^n$$
> is a categorical equivalence.

But this doesn't look quite right to me. For suppose $n\geq 1$. If the above map were a categorical equivalence, then there would be some object of $\mathcal{O}^\otimes \times_S \{1\}$ which is equivalent to an object of $\mathcal{O}^\otimes \times_S \{0\}$ in $\mathcal{O}^\otimes \times_S \Delta ^n.$ But then $0$ and $1$ would be equivalent in the $\infty$-category $\Delta^n,$ which is absurd. The same sort of error seems to reside in the proof of Proposition 2.3.4.5.

So my question is: **Am I misunderstanding something? If I am not, are there some alternative ways to prove Propositions 2.3.4.5 and 2.3.4.9?** Any help/comment/suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely 2.3.4.9 should need very little specific to operads — this local-to-global property should hold generally for adjoints of any functor!  That is: given *any* family of functors $U : C \to D$ over a space $S$, if for each vertex $s \in S$, $U_s : C_s \to D_s$ has a left adjoint, then $U$ has a fibred left adjoint over $S$.  This is because uniqueness of adjoints says that the space-over-$S$ of fibred left adjoints to $U$ is always a “mere proposition”, i.e. $(-1)$-truncated over $S$, [cont’d]

Comment: [cont’d] and so a section of it over the discrete space $DS_0$ (as provided by the “local adjoints” hypothesis) extends along the cover $DS_0 \to S$ to give a global section, since “cover” = “$(–1)$-connected” = orthogonal to $(–1)$-truncated.  (I’m using the HoTT indexing convention here as I’m more familiar with it; iirc it’s off-by-one on connectedness compared to Lurie.)

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine : this kind of result is also proved in HA in the section on relative adjunctions, e.g. 7.3.2.6.. But I'm not sure this is what Alg_O(C) is supposed to be (I think it is probably the category of sections of such a thing, which would also probably work; but I'm not familiar with this part of HA)

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Thanks for your attention. But as Maxime points out, the situation here seems to be slightly different from the one you have in mind. ($\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal{O_c},\mathcal{C})$ is not a fiber of some map into $S$.)